# How to draw desired matrix using c++?

Tags: c++, c++11

Draw below matrix using c++. Problem require a function, which could be called into the main().

```
x!x!x
~~~~~
x!x!x
~~~~~
x!x!x
```

I tried comparing the location 0,2,4. and tried to print but is there any other way to do this problem ?

Comment: Incoming critic on the question in 3..2..1

Comment: Another "do my homework' question

Comment: 1) Use 2 nested loops, one for rows and one for columns. 2) Look up `std::width` or `std::cout.width`.  3) Use an `if` statement for placing separator characters in rows. 4) Search the internet for "C++ tic-tac-toe example" for similar examples.

Answer (score 0):

If the matrix are characters, you could do something like this:

```
char board[] =
    "x|x|x\n"
    "-+-+-\n"
    "x|x|x\n"
    "-+-+-\n"
    "x|x|x\n"
    ;
```

The columns containing the character `'x'` are located at indices 0, 2, 4, 14, 16, 18, 26, 28, 30.  Row indices are 0, 14, and 28.

*Hint:  there are 6 characters per row.*
Hint:  columns indices are (row * (characters per row)) + ((column - 1) * (2 characters per row))

This has the nice benefit of only requirement one statement to print:

```
std::cout.write(&board[0], sizeof(board) - 1U);
```

The `- 1U` is so that the terminating nul is not sent to `cout`.